# how to start parallel process on specific core?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gpu

I am building an image analysis workflow that take advantage of the [bfast](https://github.com/diku-dk/bfast) library. what I was doing so far is using the future lib as such:

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor: # use all the available CPU/GPU
    executor.map(partial(bfast_stack, **bfast_params), sub_stack_files)
```

with `sub_stack_files` being chunks of my image and `bfas_stack` the function that run the actual model. The process was extremely slow and talking with the owner of the repository ([github#26](https://github.com/diku-dk/bfast/issues/26)) it seems that `bfastMonitor` only run on the first GPU (index = 0) if it's not specified.

So my question is simple can I get the core index number when I run a parralel program in Python so that I can use the appropriate core number when running the bfast model ?

**nota bene**
I am open to other libs

Comment: The operating system shifts processes around between cores, and python does not have control over this. `ThreadPoolExecutor` will use python `Threading` which is subject to the GIL, and won't get better perf than single threaded. Nothing in python standard library uses GPU.

Comment: That is really unfortunate, I'll continue investigating from my side then

Comment: process / thread scheduling is much lower level than you typically have access to. It's a different story with hardware like GPU usually, but cpu is controlled by the OS